# Need an Automatic Editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

what I'm looking for is some something similar to the automatically generated "delete" and "Create" functions that are created in MVC.  I'd like one that is used to update a record.  Preferably it would work much like a gridview (I'd prefer not to mix in ASPX pages), but if it creates a separate form, I'm okay with that too.

Comment: I honestly don't know what/where your problem/question is.

Comment: Can you explain this in a broader way ?

Comment: Scaffolding for updates?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started is to scaffold a controller. In Visual Studio right-click the Controller folder, Add > Controller, you'll have the option to scaffold a controller with Read/Write actions or using Entity Framework. In the latter case you'll need a create model to base it on before hand.

Once you've done this have a look for the Edit ActionResult, this allows you to edit single records. It's possible to do multiple records but it take a fair bit more work.